# Suppressing debug messages from neptune library

Tags: python

Is there a way to suppress the DEBUG messages outputted by the NEPTUNE library?
https://github.com/neptune-ai/neptune-client

This is what I am doing currently:

```
tracker = neptune.init(project=f'WORKSPACE/PROJECT_NAME',
                       capture_hardware_metrics=False,
                       source_files=[],
                       capture_stdout=False,
                       capture_stderr=False)
```

These are the DEBUG messages I get:

```
2022-05-03  11:31:58 DEBUG https://app.neptune.ai:443 "POST /api/leaderboard/v1/attributes/ping?experimentId=aaa HTTP/1.1" 200 0
2022-05-03  11:32:08 DEBUG ping({'experimentId': 'aaa', '_request_options': {'timeout': 10, 'connect_timeout': 10}})
```

Comment: You can turn off logging of source code by passing an empty list to the source_files argument of 

`neptune.init():
run = neptune.init(..., source_files=[])`

Comment: @Thornily, I am already doing that, but still get tons of DEBUG messages

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no other way then

Comment: Have I answered your question below? If not please let me know if further investigation is necessary.

Comment: I updated my answer to include an option that allows for you to fine tune what messages you want to send (based on logging level) to Neptune via the built in NeptuneHandler. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

It seems counterintuitive, but passing `mode=debug` mode to Neptune will surpress Neptune related DEBUG messages:

```
tracker = neptune.init(
    project=f'WORKSPACE/PROJECT_NAME',
    mode="debug",
    capture_hardware_metrics=False,
    source_files=[],
    capture_stdout=False,
    capture_stderr=False
)
```

Another way to enable this functionality is to set environment variable `CONNECTION_MODE`.

## Option 2

If you want to be able to fine tune which messages are logged to the Neptune website/server, consider using the `NeptuneHandler` provided by the Neptune client.

Example:

```
>>> import logging
>>> import neptune.new as neptune
>>> from neptune.new.integrations.python_logger import NeptuneHandler
>>> logger = logging.getLogger("root_experiment")
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
>>> run = neptune.init(project="neptune/sandbox")
>>> npt_handler = NeptuneHandler(run=run) # you can also pass `level=logging.INFO` here
>>> logger.addHandler(npt_handler)
>>> logger.info("Starting data preparation")
...
>>> logger.info("Data preparation done")
```

The above example sends all logs above log levels of severity > DEBUG to the Neptune website/server. For reference, log level severity for python are as follows (CRITICAL > ERROR > WARNING > INFO > DEBUG). I've included Python's documentation on this topic in the references below.

## References

https://docs.neptune.ai/you-should-know/connection-modes#debug

https://docs.neptune.ai/api-reference/integrations/python-logger

https://github.com/neptune-ai/neptune-client/blob/8950d174336ce689480607870119a0b276ebbacf/neptune/new/integrations/python_logger.py

https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#when-to-use-logging

Comment: thanks, won't this stop all logging to the Neptune website as well? I still want to log values to the Neptune website, just don't want to see the debug messages

Answer (score 0):

You can completely disable stdout.
Use the following functions:

```py
import sys, os

# Disable
def disable_stdout():
    sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')

# Restore
def enable_stdout():
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
```

Example:

```py
disable_stdout()

<Code to Run without logging/printing>

enable_stdout()
```

WARNING:
This is a quite dangerous approach, as it will probably hide other important/usefull messages.
Use it as a last resort

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `logging` module.

Simply, import the module and get the logger instance by using `logging.getLogger`, and then use the `setLevel` function, pass in the `level` parameter as the *level* above the types of warnings you want to show(i.e. the type of problem before which you want to ignore).

Since these are debug messages, you could set a level like critical by using `logging.CRITICAL`, this would cause the debug messages from that library to be ignored.

Read https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel for more information